# TypeError: props.onAdd is not a function React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, rxjs, react-hooks

I am getting "is not a function" error for a defined prop in my React application.

I tried adding `onAdd={() => addTodo()}`, however, it did not work.

I would like to know why the error is occurring and how to fix the error.

Please see the [error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsTXV.png)

**TodoForm.js - where I accept my props**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const TodoForm = (props) => {

    const [input, setInput] = useState('');

    const handleSubmit = e => {
    
    // console.log(e);
    e.preventDefault();
    
    props.onAdd({
        id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000),
        text: input
    });
    setInput('');
};

return(
    <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <input type="text"
             placeholder="Add a todo"
              value={input} name="text"
               className='todo-input' 
               onChange={e => setInput(e.target.value)} />
                <input type="submit" value="Add todo"></input>
            
        </form>
    </div>
);
}
export default TodoForm;
```

**TodoList.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import TodoForm from './TodoForm';

const TodoList = () => {
   const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

   const addTodo = todo => {
       if(!todo.text || /^\s*$/.test(todo.text)){
           return;
       }

       const newTodos = [todo, ...todos];

       setTodos(newTodos);
       console.log(...todos);
       console.log("is working");
   }

   return(
       <div>
           <h1>Waht's the plan for today?</h1>
           <TodoForm onAdd={() => addTodo()} />
       </div>
   );
}

export default TodoList;
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you save the file , something is wrong , you code should still work , not how you want it to work but it should work , however the solution provided  by Sean is 100% correct .
"`onAdd={() => addTodo()}`, however, it did not work." here you simply create a function that return a function.